# drupal 7 drush cc all gives a bracket ( } )

Tags: drupal-7, phpstorm, drush

When I do Drush cc all for my Drupal project it gives me a `}`. so somewhere in my code is a bracket `}` to much.

I have more than 1000 php files. is there some way to find it easily?

```
drush cc all

}

all cache was cleared in /opt/drupal web                           [success]
```

I work on Ubuntu and use phpstorm

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is in one of your PHP files, you might use an automated code-checking tool. PHP CLI offers the `php -l` option. Otherwise, you can use PHPLint: http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/

**EDIT**: For instance, from your Ubuntu terminal, you might use a command like the following for all your `*.module` files:

`find . -name "*.module" -exec php -l {} \;`

(you can add more extensions to the `find` command if necessary, see https://superuser.com/questions/416425/using-find-for-multiple-file-extensions for details.

Hope it helps,

Comment: if u do find . -name "*.*" -exec php -l {} \; he checks all files but at the end i cant see witch have errors. My college reverted some contrib modules and then it disabpeard so now wi will revert them one bye one to find the problem thanks for the help

Comment: You can redirect the output to a file and then check it with an editor, or else you can add something like `|  grep -v "No syntax errors"` at the end of the command line, in order to see only which ones have a syntax error (the output text might be different, I am not running php -l on Ubuntu).